# Общее количество строк, которое было в какое-то время, PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Существует таблица с id и датой регистрации,
необходимо получать таблицу с количеством пользователей зарегистрированных в определенный момент времени.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ожидаю получить:

```
count              created 
2                  2022-12-14 
3                  2022-12-15 
5                  2022-12-20
```

По сути мне нужно чтобы для каждого created был запрос от 2022 до created, но такое я нашел только как общую выборку по бд, а не группировку

Comment: ```COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('day', created))``` Ну или генератор календаря + коррелированный подзапрос в SELECT.

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось!